# How to get a relation between the survey entity and the response routing in Dynamics CRM VOC?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am working on a piece of software that collects the "questions" from a Dynamics CRM which uses [this technique](http://survivingcrm.com/2016/03/voice-of-the-customer-conditional-questions/) to navigate the survey.

So far any of the attributes I see cannot be used to create a link between the questions and the responserouting collection I get.

Is it possible to connect the responserouting to the question it listens to?
And is it then also possible to connect it to the question it manages?

So far I cannot find any connecting attribute, which I can use to identify the questions and/or responserouting.

This function collects the questions

```
    private static DataCollection<Entity> GetQuestions(Guid _surveyId)
    {
        // Find survey question responses
        QueryExpression questionQuery = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = "msdyn_question",
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
            Criteria = new FilterExpression
            {
                Conditions =
                {
                    new ConditionExpression
                    {
                        AttributeName = "msdyn_surveyid",
                        Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                        Values = {_surveyId}
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        return connection.service.RetrieveMultiple(questionQuery).Entities;
    }
```

This function returns the ResponseRouting objects:

```
    private static DataCollection<Entity> GetRouting(Guid _surveyId, string query)
    {
        // Find survey question responses
        QueryExpression questionQuery = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = query,
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
            Criteria = new FilterExpression
            {
                Conditions =
                {
                    new ConditionExpression
                    {
                        AttributeName = "msdyn_survey",
                        Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                        Values = {_surveyId}
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        return connection.service.RetrieveMultiple(questionQuery).Entities;
    }
```

I do get the corresponding ResponseRouting object, but I cannot find any point of reference for where and how I can format the earlier questions.

This is all based on c# code, I need to be able to reach it through the code otherwise it isn't helpfull...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct relationship between Survey question and Response routing. But in Response routing record, when you add Condition you have to choose the Question.

So the needed link is between Condition record of Response routing & Question.

> Response routing rule  has 3  parts:
>   **General Tab** (contains the name
>   of the rule and name of the survey)
>   **Conditions Tab** ( contains the
>   conditions to be met on the survey)
>   **Actions** (contains the actions
>   to be taken when the conditions are met)

[image]

[Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/mscrmshop/archive/2016/05/25/response-routing-rules-in-voice-of-the-customer-s-surveys-in-crm2016).

**Update:**

Response Condition got `N:1` relationship with Question, Response Routing & Survey.

Since you already got questions list, iterate through each question & using below method you can get the related Response Routing.

```
private static DataCollection<Entity> GetRoutingConditions(Guid _questionId, Guid _surveyId)
{
    // Find Routing conditions
    QueryExpression routingConditionQuery = new QueryExpression
    {
        EntityName = "msdyn_responsecondition",
        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
        Criteria = new FilterExpression
        {
            Conditions =
            {
                new ConditionExpression
                {
                    AttributeName = "msdyn_questionid",
                    Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                    Values = {_questionId}
                }
            }
        },
        LinkEntities =
        {
            new LinkEntity
            {
                LinkFromEntityName = "msdyn_responsecondition",
                LinkToEntityName = "msdyn_responserouting",
                LinkFromAttributeName = "msdyn_responseroutingid",
                LinkToAttributeName = "msdyn_responseroutingid",
                LinkCriteria =
                {
                    Filters =
                    {
                        new FilterExpression
                        {
                            FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                            Conditions =
                            {
                                new ConditionExpression("msdyn_surveyid", ConditionOperator.Equal, _surveyId)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    return connection.service.RetrieveMultiple(routingConditionQuery).Entities;
}
```

Comment: I have read that page but it is not the info I am looking for, is there some source somewhere where I can read about how I can **programmatically** collect these  values. Because I need them to collate into a flow for a custom system.

Comment: @HeadhunterXamd share the c# code what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Small update: I have almost all the info for the branching, the only thing I am missing is the connection between the responseActions and the question it should hide.

Comment: removed the change.