# get the surveyquestion which the ResponseAction should hide or show

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am trying to find (through code) the relation between the ResponseAction of a Routing Response and the Question it should show or hide. 
I cannot find a reference to the question in the attributes of the ResponseAction. Is there data I need to make the link?

this is a followup from my previous question:

[How to get a relation between the survey entity and the response routing in Dynamics CRM VOC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48300035/how-to-get-a-relation-between-the-survey-entity-and-the-response-routing-in-dyna)

EDIT:

```
    private static DataCollection<Entity> GetEntities(Guid id, string entityname, string comparisonAttribute, Guid surveyGuid)
    {
        QueryExpression conditionQuery = new QueryExpression
        {
            EntityName = entityname,
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
            Criteria = new FilterExpression
            {
                Conditions =
                {
                    new ConditionExpression
                    {
                        AttributeName = comparisonAttribute,
                        Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                        Values = { id }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        return connection.service.RetrieveMultiple(conditionQuery).Entities;
    }
```

I call this function with:

```
GetEntities(entity.Id, "msdyn_responseaction", "msdyn_responseroutingid", surveyId);
```

the entity is based on the responserouting object from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the Question lookup in the below Response Action form (`msdyn_responseaction`):

[image]

Query this attribute in your Retrieve call using QueryExpression columnset.

Edit:

After chat session, it appears to be some setup issue in Survey Response Action. The [Routing](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AgIWgW3pnMnQjc87uyMeju_ZtT9ujg) itself not working.

Comment: I got the query setup, but I am not getting the question data. I get all the other values, without the question.

Comment: @HeadhunterXamd code looks right. are you sure you have setup the client action? any server action is there & verify the resultant EntityCollection for question attribute to show us the missing question lookup value..

Comment: On the CRM the client action is filled in, while I cannot find the question attribute on the responseaction object.

Comment: I will accept your answer because it is essentially correct :P